# Node Request Library: Setting the Read timeout

Tags: node.js, request, timeout

I have a server which responds quickly, but then has to grab data from an external source.  I believe this is causing a read timeout.

```
    getSubdeviceStatus(){
    var parent = this;
    let fullUrl = this.baseUrl + this.getSubdeviceStatusEndpoint;
    console.log(fullUrl);
    console.log(this.authHeaders);
    console.log(this.className+ ": getSubdeviceStatus called on Device: "+this.deviceGuid);
    request.get({
        headers: this.authHeaders,
        url:     fullUrl,
        timeout: 300000,
    }, function(error, response, body){
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("Response for "+fullUrl);
            console.log(response.headers)
            console.log(body.length);
            //parent.subdevices = [];
            let json_response = JSON.parse(body);
            //iterate through our updates
            }

        }else{
            console.log(this.className +": getSubdeviceStatus failed.")
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

How do I manually set the read timeout?

Comment: Hey John, did you find a solution for this?